# VBA Dynamic Range Vlookup Defined Name

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

world! Well, this is my first time in here, so dont be angry if I did something wrong.

I need to  populate a ComboBox RowSource based on another Combobox value.
[Userform with combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4zai.png)

In my project there are two ComboBox that are dependent: Laboratorie and Test

They initialize with rowsources made in Defined Name with respectly all laboratories (TodosLaboratorios) and all tests (TodasAmostragens)

I have 464 lab tests and 5 laboratories. Not all laboratories can do all types of tests.

Exemple:

```
     TEST                               | LABORATORIE
     álcool benzilio                    | ALAC
     n-Butano (vide álcoo n-butílico)   | ALAC, ENVIRON
     Clorobenzeno                       | ALAC, ENVIRON, SOLUTECH
```

I have lists in Defined Names with all tests done by an expecific lab, so if I choose a lab at my first ComboBox the other ComboBox RowSource is populated with the expecific lab tests list.

```
    Private Sub labb1_Change()
    
        If labb1.Value = "" Then labb1.RowSource = "todoslaboratorios"
        If labb1.Value = "ALAC" Then lab1.RowSource = "labALAC"
        If labb1.Value = "ENVIRON" Then lab1.RowSource = "labENVIRON"
        If labb1.Value = "FIRJAN" Then lab1.RowSource = "labFIRJAN"
        If labb1.Value = "SOLUTECH" Then lab1.RowSource = "labSOLUTECH"
        If labb1.Value = "UNIANALISYS" Then lab1.RowSource = "labUNIANALISYS"
    
    End Sub
```

I'm trying to do the inverse, as I choose an expecific test, I want to the ComboBox of laboratories be populated only with the labs that can do that test.

I have a sheet with all the labs, tests and their prices. I organized the tests/lab in this way:
[tests and labs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlk85.png)

I didn't figured out how to do a defined name dynamic range with a dynamic reference... I tried things like:

```
  =index($t3$, match($t$1, todasamostragens, 0), 
         offset($t$3,match($t$1, todasamostragens, 0),0,0,5)
```

Am I in the right way? Can anyone help me achive my goal?

All respect for the programmers here.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem with a different approach.

I ordered the tests in one line and placed the laboratories in each column of the specific test.[image: tests with laboratories]

Then I used .find to search that range and create an defined name.

For the tests ComboBox:

```
Private Sub Amostragens()

            Dim teste As Variant
            
            Dim linharange As range
            Dim colunarange As range
            'Dim Lrow As Long
            Dim range As range
            Dim rangeD As range
                      
            Set range = Worksheets("lab").range("t3:ro3")
            
            
            If lab1.Value = "" Then
                labb1.RowSource = "todoslaboratorios"
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
            If lab1.Value <> "" Then
                With range
                     If .Find(what:=lab1.Value) <> "" Then
                     
                     Set linharange = range.Find(what:=lab1.Value).Offset(2, 0)
                     
'                     Lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", _
'                     AFTER:=range(linharange.Address()), _
'                     searchorder:=xlPrevious, _
'                     searchdirection:=xlNext, _
'                     MatchCase:=False).Row
                     
                     Set colunarange = range.Find(what:=lab1.Value).Offset(6, 0)
                     
                     Set rangeD = .range(linharange.Offset(-2, -19), colunarange.Offset(-2, -19))
                     rangeD.Name = "AmostragensLab"
                     
                     End If
                 End With
                
                labb1.RowSource = "AmostragensLab"
                
            End If
End Sub
```

For the lab ComboBox:

```
Private Sub Laboratorios()

            If lab1.Value = "" Then
                    If labb1.Value = "" Then labb1.RowSource = "todoslaboratorios"
                    If labb1.Value = "ALAC" Then lab1.RowSource = "labALAC"
                    If labb1.Value = "ENVIRON" Then lab1.RowSource = "labENVIRON"
                    If labb1.Value = "FIRJAN" Then lab1.RowSource = "labFIRJAN"
                    If labb1.Value = "SOLUTECH" Then lab1.RowSource = "labSOLUTECH"
                    If labb1.Value = "UNIANALISYS" Then lab1.RowSource = "labUNIANALISYS"
                Exit Sub
            End If

            If lab1.Value <> "" Then
            Exit Sub
            End If

End Sub
```

On change:

```
        Private Sub labb1_Change()

        Laboratorios
        valorlab

        End Sub
            
        Private Sub lab1_change()
            
        Amostragens
        valorlab
            
        End Sub
```

I'm learning VBA and I'll appreciate sugestions to improve this code.